# How to get element from Embed/Object of HTML page with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, embed, getelementbyid, getelementsbytagname

I have included Object/Embed in HTML-file of application to display another web page. i.e.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no">
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>PhoneGap</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="master.css" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="init();">
    <!-- <embed id='embadedContent' height = 400 width= '100%' src="http://192.168.2.44:9191/testtwo/"/> -->
    <object height = 400 width= '100%' data="http://192.168.2.44:9191/testtwo/">
        <param name="quality" value="high">
    </object>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, I want to get reference of components which are in Webpage (`http://192.168.2.44:9191/testtwo/`) like button, textfield, etc. so that based on logic I can change property of these elements.

Comment: if you are loading webpage consider using iframe and use this to get elements document.getElementById('myframe').contentWindow.document

Comment: @CodeiSir: I think that was just meant to show what the URL of his page was (which turns out to be relevant).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read data in HTML object tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36659202/read-data-in-html-object-tag)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `id` tag to later refere to the element, e.g. like this: `id="myObject1"`

```
<object id="myObject1" height = 400 width= '100%' data="http://192.168.2.44:9191/testtwo/">
 <param name="quality" value="high">
</object>
```

And then you can access it via JavaScript:

```
var myObject1 = document.getElementById("myObject1")
myObject1.style.height = "200px"
```

Comment: That gives the OP the `object` element, not *"components which are in Webpage"*.

Comment: You can use `object` and `embed` for embedding pages, much the way you can with `iframe`s, yes.