# Read data in HTML object tag

Tags: javascript, html, object-tag

I have a text file stored on the server and an object in HTML like this:

```
<object id="data" type="text/plain" data="test.txt"></object>
```

How can I read the contents of `test.txt` in Javascript? What I have so far is:

```
var data = document.getElementByID("data");
```

But I can't figure out how to read the HTML document inside the object tag.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14446538/5965782) an example to read the content then insert it

Comment: What is purpose of using `object` element, instead of `iframe` element to display text document? See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object at Permitted content

Comment: _"But I can't figure out how to read the HTML document inside the object tag."_  `.html` document does not appear to be set at `data`? `data` is set to `.txt` file, `type` set to `text/plain`.

Comment: The object tag automatically takes the text file and wraps it in a new HTML file. According to the firefox inspector, it looks something like `<object ...> #document <html><body>[Contents of test.txt]</body></html></object>`

Comment: Try `var data = document.getElementByID("data").contentDocument.documentElement;`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `object` tag has to make a separate request to the server and then load that content. Meanwhile, your JavaScript has already executed and "misses the bus."

Run your code inside the `onload` event of the `object`.

Then use `.contentDocument.body.childNodes[0].innerHTML` to view the text file.

```
var object = document.getElementById("data");
object.onload = function() {
    var data = object.contentDocument.body.childNodes[0].innerHTML;
    // use the data
};
```

Comment: After a ton of trial and error, I finally figured out how to do it! Google wasn't much help for once... `text/plain` puts a `pre` tag inside the `object`, so that's why `childNodes` is there.

Comment: BTW, for people trying to test my code -- I couldn't use JSFiddle or even a `file://` kind of HTML file in order to test this. (It thinks there is XSS going on a throws an error). I had to load it from my `localhost` in order to test it.

Comment: this doesn't work, maybe not anymore as browsers have since restricted local loading. I got null data

Comment: @4castle could you explain more, because the above example doesn't work for me either, as it is

Comment: @intergallactic The file referenced by the `<object>` tag's `data` attribute must be a file that is hosted on the same server as the one that serves the HTML file that uses this JavaScript. Otherwise, you will need to configure [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) for the server that hosts the file so that other servers are allowed to request it. This code works fine once you are hosting the files properly.

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple function and button as an example.
Just copy the html and js code and it should work for you.
Just make sure you create the appropriate txt or html file for the object to import.

[edit]
Pay attention to the object line.
especially the data="test.txt" portion of the object.
If you do not create test.txt and add some text to the first line, the script will not work.
[end edit]

```js
function getObjectData()
{
    //alert("getObjectData");
    
    var myData = "";
    var object = document.getElementById("data");
    
    //get data inside object data
    var myData = object.contentDocument.body.childNodes[0].innerHTML;

    alert("myData => " + myData + " <= myData" );
}
```

```css
#data{
    height: 36px;
    border: solid 1px red;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <object id="data" type="text/plain" data="test.txt"></object>
</div>
<br />
<button onclick="getObjectData()">Get Object Data</button>
```

Comment: I receive: {
  "message": "TypeError: object.contentDocument is null",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 28,
  "colno": 18
}