# Execute javascript after loading generic handler asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, pdf, ashx

I have a gridview with a list of pdf files. When the user clicks a pdf, it displays the file inline on the page. I want to execute some javascript after the pdf has been loaded but I cannot get this to work. The issue is that the pdf loads after everything else, so the load event fires before the pdf begins to load.

My first approach was to use an iframe. The inner page would retrieve the file and write the data to the response. As mentioned previously, the load event occurred before loading the pdf and I need it to trigger after. The current code uses a generic handler ashx to load the pdf inline. How do I trigger an event to execute javascript, after the pdf data is loaded server side from the ashx generic handler?

Aspx page:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "View")
    {
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        string Id = GridView1.DataKeys[index].Value.ToString();
        HtmlGenericControl myObject = new HtmlGenericControl();
        myObject.TagName = "object";
        Panel1.Controls.Add(myObject);
        myObject.Attributes.Add("data", "GetPdf.ashx?Id=" + Id);
    }
}
```

Generic handler ashx:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("GetPdf.ashx started");
    string Id = context.Request.QueryString["Id"];
    byte[] data = GetPdf(Id);
    context.Response.ClearContent();
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-disposition", "inline");
    context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", data.Length.ToString());
    context.Response.BinaryWrite(data);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("GetPdf.ashx is done");
    context.Response.End();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting an event handler for the `object` tag's `onload` event? I'm not sure if that will work across all browsers, but I also don't know which browsers you require it to work on.

Worst-case scenario you could use `setTimeout` to rapidly poll for the PDF's existence.

[Here's a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36659261/1062614) that may help you with both aspects.